# How to concatenate values of one Dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate all values of only one dataframe column:

Please consider a dataframe df:

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
Dates = {'Day': [1,2,3,4,5]}
df = DataFrame(Dates, columns=['Day'])
df
```

I want to get the string "12345".

I writed this function:

```
def ConcatVols(df,col):
    str = ''
    for indx, row in df.iterrows():
        str += row[col]
    return str
```

I call it by:

```
ConcatVols(df,'Day').
```

It does the job but I find it not very  pretty.
So I ask me if a better solution exists (probably).

Perhaps with adding `df['Day'].T` columns content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` with convert column to strings:

```
out = ''.join(df['Day'].astype(str))
```

So your function should be:

```
def ConcatVols(df,col):
    return ''.join(df[col].astype(str))
```